# VB WPF to C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, converters

I'm attempting to move from using VB WPF to C# WPF, What I have attempted so far is using an online converter because of the amount of code I have. The problem being that I have come into some troubles understanding some errors presented and being a beginner in C# I'm a little lost.

The code below is what I'm currently using with standard VB WPF and work perfectly fine and a copy of what the c# converter changes it into. (Note I have added Bing Maps WPF Reference to both VB and C#)

```
Private Sub Aberdeen() Handles BTNCounty.Click
    If TXTCounty.Text = "Aberdeen" Then

        Dim CountyLocation(2) As Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location

        CountyLocation(0) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(57.143652, -2.1056584)
        CountyLocation(1) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(57.143652, -2.1056584)
        CountyLocation(2) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(57.124838, -2.0991633)


Dim names = New String() {"Aberdeen Central",   "Aberdeen Lochnagar", "Aberdeen Kincorth"}

 For index = 0 To CountyLocation.Length - 1
            Dim Pin = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()

            Dim CoordinateTip = New ToolTip()
            CoordinateTip.Content = names(index)

            Pin.Location = CountyLocation(index)
            Pin.ToolTip = CoordinateTip
            BingMap.Children.Add(Pin)



        Next


    End If
End Sub
```

Below is the example of the converted code into c#

```
private void Aberdeen()
{

if (TXTCounty.Text == "Aberdeen") {
    Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location[] CountyLocation = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location[3];

    CountyLocation(0) = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(57.143652, -2.1056584);
    CountyLocation(1) = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(57.143652, -2.1056584);
    CountyLocation(2) = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(57.124838, -2.0991633);


    dynamic names = new string[] {
        "Aberdeen Central",
        "Aberdeen Lochnagar",
        "\tAberdeen Kincorth"
    };

    for (index = 0; index <= CountyLocation.Length - 1; index++) {
        dynamic Pin = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin();

        dynamic CoordinateTip = new ToolTip();
        CoordinateTip.Content = names(index);

        Pin.Location = CountyLocation(index);
        Pin.ToolTip = CoordinateTip;
        BingMap.Children.Add(Pin);



    }


}
}
```

I recieve 3 errors which I was wondering if you could tell me what they mean and how to resolve the issue?

1. CountyLocation is a variable but used like a method?

2 The name index does not exist in the current context?

3 System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ToolTip is a property but is used like a type?

Any help would be much appreciated as this very much foreign territory for me.

Comment: Your VB.net code is a Form Project.  The C# converted to a console application.  Error 1 is due to the textbox on the form doesn't exist in the console application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see the answers inline.
The main issue is that the converter has converted all your type inference calls (`Dim variable = ...`) to dynamics, which is incorrect. You should use `var` for type inference.

```
private void Aberdeen()
{

    if (TXTCounty.Text == "Aberdeen") {
        Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location[] CountyLocation = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location[3];

        // Error 1: Setting array variables is done using square brackets, otherwise it's considered a method invocation
        CountyLocation[0] = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(57.143652, -2.1056584);
        CountyLocation[1] = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(57.143652, -2.1056584);
        CountyLocation[2] = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(57.124838, -2.0991633);

        // extra: you don't need dynamic here, just var will do
        var names = new string[] {
            "Aberdeen Central",
            "Aberdeen Lochnagar",
            "\tAberdeen Kincorth"
        };

        // Error 2: you need to declare the index variable (added var)
        for (var index = 0; index <= CountyLocation.Length - 1; index++) {
            // Error 3: don't need dynamic here
            var Pin = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin();

            // don't need dynamic here 
            var CoordinateTip = new ToolTip();
            // Same as error 1: Array access is done with square brackets
            CoordinateTip.Content = names[index];

            // Same as error 1: Array access is done with square brackets    
            Pin.Location = CountyLocation[index];
            Pin.ToolTip = CoordinateTip;
            BingMap.Children.Add(Pin);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: The two array accessors also need fixing (e.g. `names(index)` should be `names[index]`).

Comment: Good catch, added it